# Two customization packages customizing the same screen

Tags: acumatica

Is it possible to have two separate customization packages modifying the same screen / screen section (e.g., header) in the same instance?   I'm running into a conflict during validation because of this.  What's the best way to alleviate that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized from talking with other developers that increasing the level allows this to compile.

Thanks, Brendan.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are using the extensibility framework (AEF) you should be able to. Also make sure you set your customization publish levels to different values found on the customization screen where you create and maintain your list of customization. What changes have you made? More details will better help answer your question.

Comment: I ended up answering my own question.  Thanks for your help, Brendan.

Comment: Awesome. Don't forget to mark your answer as the answer.